# Can a mobile game developer ban an account for excessive purchases that were cancelled/refunded by the payment provider?

Tags: consumer-protection

Can a mobile game developer ban an account for purchases that were cancelled/refunded by amazon appstore? It seems that amazon allowed $50k worth of in app purchases to be delivered without actually getting payment for by allowing the purchase to go through and putting them in a "pending" order status.

> Though your order has already been delivered, we couldn’t charge your
>   account for your order (#D01-0381849-xxxxxxx), due to a problem with
>   the payment method you provided. We may attempt to reprocess payment
>   for your order in a few days using the payment method you provided.
>   Please go to the following page to make sure that the payment
>   information for your account is correct, and so that we have a valid
>   payment method for your future orders:
>
> https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/your-account/order-summary.html?orderID=D01-0381849-xxxxxxx
>
> A charge can be declined for a variety of reasons. If you used a
>   credit or debit card for your order, please contact the bank that
>   issued your card for more information on why the charge was declined.
>
> If we don't receive payment from you within the next 30 day(s), your
>   order will be cancelled.
>
> If you have any questions, go to:
>   https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/contact-us/
>
> Note: This e-mail was sent from a notification-only address that
>   cannot accept incoming e-mail. Please do not reply to this message.
>
> Thank you for shopping at Amazon.com.

A month later the game developer banned the account because amazon refunded all the purchases. Although they werent actually ever paid for so how a refund could be made is beyond me...

Theres a few issues actually...

The game developer is now demanding repayment for the orders amazon cancelled.. but is demanding more than the amount that was actually refunded when amazon cancelled the pending purchases... can they do that?.. the game developer only recieves 70% of each sale made through amazon appstore since amazon keeps 30% of every purchase made.  So if the game developer only lost 70% of every order that was cancelled/reversed by amazon... shouldnt 70% be the amount to be repaid?

Another issue is that these orders apparently were "cancelled/reversed" by amazon 1 minute after the purchase was made... but yet both amazon and the game developer allowed purchases to keep being made for about a month... letting the bill rack up to $50k. Why wait a whole month for someone to make $50k worth of in app purchases when orders were cancelled 1 minute after being made? And then wait a whole month before doing anything about it (banning the account and demanding repayment in order to lift the ban) 
both amazon and the game developer should not have allowed purchase after purchase without doing anything about it til after the total outstanding balance accrued to $50k...

Any thoughts, opinions, help, direction on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can any service provider ban a customer if there are repeated payment issues? Yes. Game developers are no exception.